# Expect scripting - extracting userID

Tags: shell, expect

I want to get the terminal userID by using whoami command. I have given my script below, but it just returns the command name, instead of username?

How can I get terminal user id using whoami command?

My code is,

```
send "whoami\r"
      set timeout 5
      expect -re {([a-z]+)} {
       set jobid $expect_out(0,string)
      }
      send_user "\r\nUSER $jobid\r\n"
}
```

Output for the above code is,

```
asisdtt-exp7$ whoami
USER whoami
kandabap
asisdtt-exp7$ exit
```

When I hardcode the first letter of my expected userID (kandabap), I am getting the answer correct. That code is,

```
send "whoami\r"
      set timeout 5
      expect -re {k([a-z]+)} {
       set jobid $expect_out(0,string)
      }
      send_user "\r\nUSER $jobid\r\n"
```

Output,

```
asisdtt-exp7$ whoami
kandabap
asisdtt-exp7$ 
USER kandabap
```

I am very much confused.

Comment: Why you're trying to use `expect` for that? What exactly do you need?

Comment: Rush, I actually never thought of TCL and it made it pretty simple at the end.
Thanks for your help, appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're really trying to do, but this will work just fine:

```
log_user 0
spawn whoami
expect eof
set jobid $expect_out(buffer)
puts "USER $jobid"
```

Of course, none of that's really needed. You can do the same thing using plain TCL:

```
puts "USER [exec whoami]"
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks.
I never thought of TCL and it made it very simple at the end.
Thanks, Appreciated